# Usual Topology on a union of sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. Take the union of the sets 
$$X\cup Y=\{x\;|\;x\in X \;\text{or}\; x\in Y\}$$
What is the "usual" topology we put on this set $X\cup Y$? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I would for the [coherent topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology). Basically, a subset $U$ of $X \cup Y$ will be open iff $U\cap X$ and $U\cap Y$ are both open. The coherent topology, applied to this context, is also referred to as the topological union (the same link contains the info).

Answer (score 3):

The coherent topology is also characterized as the strongest topology on the (disjoint) union $X \cup Y$ such that the injection maps $i_X \colon X \to X \cup Y$ and $i_Y \colon Y \to X \cup Y$ are both continuous. This sounds a little like the definition of the product topology, namely the weakest topology on $X \times Y$ which makes both projections $\pi _X \colon X \times Y \to X$ and $\pi _Y \colon X \times Y \to Y$ continuous. This similarity is not a coincidence.

Comment: why did you put the word disjoint between parentheses ?